# htaccess rewrite question mark not work in url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a problem when I try change the urls

```
RewriteRule ^p=([^/]*)([a-zA-Z0-9]{9})$ p.php?v=$2

http://www.example.com/p=ac0266df0
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^p?v=([^/]*)([a-zA-Z0-9]{9})$ p.php?v=$2

http://www.example.com/p?v=ac0266df0
```

But not work. There seem to be an problem "?" question mark.

What is the correct way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

This is the rewrite rule you need to implement to make it work.

```
RewriteRule ^p=ac0266df0$ /p?v=ac0266df0&%{QUERY_STRING}
```